# How can I find max value and display text next to it in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula that will find the highest number in a column and then display the text in the cell immediately to the left of that number, i.e. find the highest grade and display the name of the student who earned that grade.  Either excel or google spreadsheet

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. This is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. Rather than explaining what you've already attempted, your questions appears to be a request for someone to do something for you. Although someone has answered your question, please take a minute to read [ask] to better understand how to improve your questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you, for example, got the names in column `A` and the grades in column `B`, you could use the `MATCH`and `INDEX` functions to return the name of the of the student with the highest grade.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))
```

Note that this formula assumes that there is only one maximum grade in the population.

Comment: Works well, thanks.  Follow-up questions- can I add a filter to the formula so it would do the same things but only for students in a certain group, i.e. their name had the value 3 in column C

Comment: In that case, you best option might be to use the filtering options in Excel.

Answer (score -1):

Order
1st 1.90    1.68
2nd 16.70   17.77
3rd 8.57    8.97
4th 0.35    0.38

```
Highest & Lowest time taken order details   
    if using the function =INDEX(AA6:AA9,MATCH(MAX(AJ6:AJ9),AJ6:AJ9,0)) & =INDEX(AA6:AA9,MATCH(MIN(AJ6:AJ9),AJ6:AJ9,0))
Based on the highest time it is matched with index and looking the equal value and display the text
```

Highest Time taken  2nd 2nd
Lowest Time Taken      4th  4th

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people ask. Part of posting a good answer is making sure it is properly [formatting](https://superuser.com/editing-help) your post so it is easy to read. Please edit your answer and format it so that it is easier to read.